# Can I have a sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr as data member?

Tags: ros, sensor-msgs, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a class that gets an sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr and there are a lot of member functions acting to this same image.
`void extractData(const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr &image)`

I was wondering if it is possible to have a data member instead of sending the pointer from one function to the other.

I've tried adding:
`sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr &image;`

But it says uninitialized reference member.
Tried also removing Const or Ptr in declaration with no success.
Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54927/can-i-have-a-sensor_msgs::image::constptr-as-data-member?/) by [kabamaru](https://answers.ros.org/users/2240/kabamaru/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2013-02-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2013-02-11**:
FYI: For some reason the text appears to me as "sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr ℑ", when the OP actually entered "sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr &image"

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-11**:
Seems fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you can.

However, you cannot have it as a reference, i.e. remove the `&` in the declaration.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kabamaru](https://answers.ros.org/users/2240/kabamaru/) on 2013-02-11**:
I don't want new objects. I want a reference or else it doesn't worth the loss in speed. I will go with passing around the smart pointer. Thanks anyway.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-11**:
That's exactly what the smart pointer is intended for.